# Flex 4 - How to remove titleText from TitleBar skin?

Tags: apache-flex, skinning, titlebar

I want to remove title text from titleBar skin but I get an error if I just comment out. I assume it means it is required skin part?

```
<!-- title -->
<!--- @copy spark.components.windowClasses.TitleBar#titleText -->
<s:Label id="titleText" minWidth="0" maxDisplayedLines="1" width="100%" />
```

I tried setting it to text="" and text="random text" but no effect. If I set a value in Main application it works but not for empty string.

Right now it shows applications name presumably from "Main-app.xml" file.

How can I get rid of it? Any help appreciated, this is really bugging me...

Edit 1: TitleBar Skin

```
<!--- The default skin class for the title bar of the Spark WindowedApplication component
      and Spark Window component when you use Flex chrome.  
      The title bar skin includes the close, minimize, and maximize buttons, the 
      title icon, and the title text.

      <p>The Flex chrome is defined by the SparkChromeWindowedApplicationSkin skin class 
      in the spark.skins.spark package. 
      To use the Flex chrome, set <code>systemChrome</code> to "none" in the application's .xml file,
      and set the <code>skinClass</code> style to spark.skins.spark.SparkChromeWindowedApplicationSkin. </p>

      @langversion 3.0
      @playerversion Flash 10
      @playerversion AIR 1.5
      @productversion Flex 4

      @see spark.components.WindowedApplication
      @see spark.components.Window
      @see spark.skins.spark.SparkChromeWindowedApplicationSkin


    This Skin is based on "TitleBar";
-->
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
             xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
             minHeight="40" creationComplete="created()" >

    <fx:Metadata>
        [HostComponent("spark.components.windowClasses.TitleBar")]
    </fx:Metadata>

    <fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">


        import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
        import mx.events.StateChangeEvent;

        /* Exclude the titleBar and scroller because they are SparkSkins and we
         * don't want to colorize them twice. */
        static private const exclusions:Array = ["titleBar"];

        override public function get colorizeExclusions():Array
        {
            return exclusions;
        }

        override protected function initializationComplete():void
        {
            useChromeColor = true;
            super.initializationComplete();
        }

        public var ifo:Boolean;

        public function created():void
        {
            this.hostComponent.parentApplication.addEventListener(StateChangeEvent.CURRENT_STATE_CHANGE, buttonToggle);
        }

        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            //trace(hostComponent.parentApplication.currentState);
            backgroundRect.radiusX = getStyle("cornerRadius");

            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        }

        private function returnButtonHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            this.hostComponent.parentApplication.currentState = "Home";
        }

        private var lastState:String;

        private function buttonToggle(event:StateChangeEvent):void
        {
            lastState = event.oldState;

            if(event.newState == "Home")
            {
                returnButton.visible = false;
                settingsButton.label = "Settings";
            }
            else if(event.newState == "MoviePage")
            {
                returnButton.visible = true;
                settingsButton.label = "Settings";
            }
            else
            {
                returnButton.visible = false;
                settingsButton.label = "Back";
            }
        }

        private function settingsButtonHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if(settingsButton.label == "Settings") // if button label is settings
            {
                hostComponent.parentApplication.currentState = "Settings";
            }
            else // if button label is back
            {
                hostComponent.parentApplication.currentState = lastState; // return to previous state
            }
        }

    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="disabled" />
        <s:State name="normalAndMaximized" stateGroups="maximizedGroup" />
        <s:State name="disabledAndMaximized" stateGroups="maximizedGroup" />
    </s:states>

    <!-- fill -->
    <!--- Defines the background color of the title bar. -->
    <s:Rect id="backgroundRect" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" >
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient id="bgFill" rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xBABABA" />
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- title bar content -->
    <s:Group id="titleBar" minHeight="40" width="100%" height="100%" left="3" right="2" >
        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout verticalAlign="middle" gap="5" />
        </s:layout>

        <!-- title bar icon -->
        <!--- @copy spark.components.windowClasses.TitleBar#titleIconImage -->
        <s:BitmapImage id="titleIconImage" minWidth="0" fillMode="clip"/>

        <!-- return button -->
        <s:Button id="returnButton" label="Return" click="returnButtonHandler(event)" visible="false" />

        <!-- title -->
        <!--- @copy spark.components.windowClasses.TitleBar#titleText -->
        <s:Label id="titleText" visible="false" includeInLayout="false" minWidth="0" maxDisplayedLines="1" width="100%" /> !!!!!!!! Error if this line is deleted !!!!!!!!!

        <!-- settings / back button -->
        <s:Button id="settingsButton" label="Settings" click="settingsButtonHandler(event)" visible="true" />

        <!-- minimize button -->
        <!--- 
            By default, the button uses the spark.skins.spark.windowChrome.MinimizeButtonSkin class
            to define the skin for the mimimized button.
            @copy spark.components.windowClasses.TitleBar#minimizeButton 
            @see spark.skins.spark.windowChrome.MinimizeButtonSkin 
        -->
        <s:Button id="minimizeButton" verticalCenter="0"
            skinClass="skins.CustomMinimizeButtonSkin" />

        <!-- maximize button -->
        <!--- 
            By default, the button uses the spark.skins.spark.windowChrome.MinimizeButtonSkin class
            to define the skin for the maximized button.
            @copy spark.components.windowClasses.TitleBar#maximizeButton
            @see spark.skins.spark.windowChrome.MaximizeButtonSkin 
        -->
        <s:Button id="maximizeButton" verticalCenter="0"
                  skinClass="skins.CustomMaximizeButtonSkin"
                  skinClass.maximizedGroup="skins.CustomRestoreButtonSkin" />

        <!-- close button -->
        <!---
            By default, the button uses the spark.skins.spark.windowChrome.MinimizeButtonSkin class
            to define the skin for the close button.
            @copy spark.components.windowClasses.TitleBar#closeButton
            @see spark.skins.spark.windowChrome.CloseButtonSkin
        -->
        <s:Button id="closeButton" verticalCenter="0"
            skinClass="skins.CustomCloseButtonSkin" />
        <s:Spacer />

    </s:Group>

</s:SparkSkin>
```

Application Skin Code Snippet:

```
<!-- layer 3: title bar + content -->
    <s:Group left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" minHeight="0" minWidth="0" >
        <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout gap="0"/>
        </s:layout>

        <!-- title bar -->
        <s:TitleBar id="titleBar" width="100%" minHeight="40" skinClass="skins.CustomTitleBarSkin" />

        <!-- content -->
        <s:Group id="contentGroup" width="100%" height="100%" minHeight="0" minWidth="0" />

    </s:Group>

    <!-- layer 4: gripper -->
    <!--- @see spark.skins.spark.windowChrome.GripperSkin -->
    <s:Button id="gripper" right="6" bottom="5" tabEnabled="false" 
              skinClass="spark.skins.spark.windowChrome.GripperSkin" /> 

</s:SparkSkin>
```

Error:

```
[SWF] Main.swf - 5,439,008 bytes after decompression
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at spark.components.windowClasses::TitleBar/commitProperties()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\airspark\src\spark\components\windowClasses\TitleBar.as:443]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8219]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateProperties()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:597]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:783]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1180]
```

Comment: Just set its `visible` and `includeInLayout` properties to `false`

Comment: Now that I look at it: `titleText` is not a required skinpart, so that can't be the issue. What is the error message you're getting.

Comment: Error is: "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." It originates in framework files and not in files I created. I also checked and I did not refer to the label's id anywhere. "TitleBar" is in the exclusions list if it matters. Could this be related to hostComponent in any way?

Comment: Can you show your whole skin?  And a sample that will recreate the error?  And the full error text?  Also let us know what component you're trying to skin; as there is no Spark component named TitleBar that I could find in the SDK.

Comment: Added Code samples, There is Title Bar Skin(you may want to create "spark.skins.spark.SparkChromeWindowedApplicationSkin" skin for main app, then you will see titlebar with skinClass property within). btw I'm using v4.6

Comment: For the kludge what happens when you set it to the non-breaking space char, or simply to a space.

Comment: Just took a look at the code in TitleBar that throws the error: looks like a bug in the framework to me. Although `titleText` is not required the TitleBar class doesn't check whether the Label actually exists in the skin before trying to set its `text` property. You might want to check the [JIRA](http://bugs.adobe.com/flex/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just took a look at the code on that line in the TitleBar class and it looked like a **bug** to me.

```
override protected function commitProperties():void {
    super.commitProperties();

    if (titleChanged) {
        titleText.text = _title;
        titleChanged = false;   
    }

....
```

As you can see, it doesn't check whether `titleText` exists before trying to set its `text` property, even though `titleText` is not a required skinpart.

So I checked the Adobe JIRA bug database. It turns that this bug has already been filed and is still unresolved:

[TitleBar lists titleText as optional, but throws exception when absent](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-27997)

The simplest **workaround** that i can think of is to leave the `titleText` Label where it is and just set its `visible` and `includeInLayout` properties to `false`.

Comment: That's good to know, at least it's not my mistake! visible+includeInLayout worked perfectly, it's a shame Flex is so buggy... Thank you for your insights!

Comment: @user998368 Well now that Flex is 'really' going open source, at least we'll be able to fix the bugs ourselves.

Comment: quick related question, I added extra buttons in TitleBar Skin but unlike close,max/restore,minimize buttons they respond to drag event (meaning container will move like it does when u drag titlebar itself).Problem is I can't see the code for drag event listeners anywhere in the skin, point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just call `event.stopPropagation()` on the MOUSE_DOWN event fired by the extra Buttons. This will prevent the mouseDownHandler of the TitleBar (which starts the dragging) from being executed as the event will no longer bubble up to the TitleBar.